# How can I find this layout file app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I study a course and it told me to edit this layout file, How can I find it please because I searched on it and I did not find it

The course instructor told me: 
""
In the new versions of Android Studio, after choosing the Empty Activity template, the layout file app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml will look like this:
""

Answer (score 2):

You must have created this file when you first created the project and this must be your launcher file. Navigate through your project and you can easily find your file.

To search, press `Shift + Shift` i.e. press `Shift` 2 times and type your file name and it will show you the results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. How you can solve it:

1. press `Shift + Shift` i.e. press `Shift` 2 times;
2. Type "Layout";
3. Select "Layout XML File";
4. Click on Finish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find this file under the layout folder in this menu:

[image]